# datepicker - next and prev button are not working after adding maxDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker as follows:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
        monthNames: datepickerResources.monthNames,
        dayNames: datepickerResources.dayNames,
        dayNamesShort: datepickerResources.dayNamesShort,
        dayNamesMin: datepickerResources.dayNamesMin,
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+4w -1d",
        numberOfMonths: [12, 1],
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            return [true, SetDateColor(date, date1, date2)];
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input1").val());
            var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#input2").val());
            if (!date1 || date2) {
                $("#input1").val(dateText);
                $("#input2").val("");
                $(this).datepicker();
            } else {
                $("#input2").val(dateText);
                $(this).datepicker();
            }
        }
    });
```

After I define the maxDate, the prev and the next button stop working and are in disable although there are active days also on the next month.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: please post HTML also. what is `$("#input1")` and `$("#input2")`? otherwise try to create running code snippet or fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You display 12 months simultaneously: `numberOfMonths: [12, 1],`.

- The `maxDate` property sets the maximum allowed date from now plus 4 weeks minus 1 day.
- The `minDate` property limits the oldest date by current date.

With such limits the possible date range is from `now` to `now + 4 weeks - 1 day`. The full range is already shown, so it is not possible to press the `next` or `prev` buttons.

If you set to show only one month (`numberOfMonths: 1,`) it is possible to go to the next page with such range.